# In search for a mathematical function that can be used for a game to make enemies harder

Tags: functions

I am currently developing a (tower defense) game in my free time.
Instead of hand-coding the stats of the enemies in the game, I would like to use a mathematical function.

Health_points_of_an_enemy_in_a_certain_level = f(level)

1. The function should return the health points of an enemy
2. The parameters of the function are the level of the enemy (the higher the level, the higher the health points)
3. The function should always have a slope > 0 (it should never decrease but it should also never converge to a particular max value)
4. The function should show something like a law of diminishing returns so that during the first levels, the enemies get stronger quickly (maybe twice as strong compared to the previous level) but later they only get slightly stronger (maybe only 5% stronger or less compared to the previous level)
5. The function will effectively only be used for level values from 1 to (maybe) 50

How could I start to create such a function?
Which parameters would allow me to tweak the curvature should I need to adjust it?
I thought of a log(x) but this does not allow me to tweak the curvature, also it's 'weird' around x=0.

The function will probably look like a saturation curve but one that never converges but will always have a slope > 0.

Many thanks for any useful hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $\log$ is a good choice for doing what you describe.  You may just need to tweak the arguments to get exactly the function you want.  For example, $\log(x+1)$ will make it not "weird" around $x=0.$  You could also change the base, try $\log_{10}(x+1)$ vs. $\ln(x+1)$.  Check out all the examples I've graphed [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_10(x%2B1)+and+log_10(3x%2B1)+and+log_10(x%5E2%2B1)+and+ln(x%2B1)+and+ln(3x%2B1)+and+ln(x%5E2%2B1)+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D50), and you can continue tweaking to get exactly what you want.

---

EDIT: To be more precise, I suggest you play around with $K\ln(Dx^n+C)$.  The constant $C \geq 1$ will fix the issues near the origin.  Increasing the constant $D$ will give a sharp increase for small values of $x$ without affecting the larger values too much.  Increasing $K \geq 1$ will increase the overall values of the function and also allow you to tweak the slope for larger values of $x$.  Setting a value of $n$ other than $1$, say $n=2$, is similar to setting $K = 2$, except there are slight differences which you should check out graphically.